# How do I capture KendoUI Multiselect data in my ASP.NET Core Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, entity-framework-core

I am trying to grab data from my two KendoUI Multiselect widgets and I can't get them to post anything to my controller.  I have three models `Products`, `Tags`, and `Categories`.  I want to post the data from my two widgets, iterate over the data and post it to the relative tables `Tags` and `Categories`.  The problem I have is that when the form is submitted, the two widgets have a count of 0 and I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Here is my basic form.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Products" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Products.Title"></label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Products.Title" class="form-control" />
    </div>


        <kendo-multiselect name="ProductTags" for="ProductTags" style="width:100%"
            placeholder="Select tags..."
            datatextfield="TagName"
            datavaluefield="Id">
            <datasource type="DataSourceTagHelperType.Ajax" page-size="80" server-filtering="true">
                <transport>
                    <read url="@Url.Action("TagVirtualRead", "Products")" />
                </transport>
            </datasource>
            <virtual value-mapper="TagMapper" />
            <popup-animation>
                <open duration="500" />
                <close duration="500" />
            </popup-animation>
        </kendo-multiselect>

    <kendo-multiselect name="ProductCategories" for="ProductCategories" style="width:100%"
        placeholder="Select categories..."
        datatextfield="CategoryName"
        datavaluefield="Id">
        <datasource type="DataSourceTagHelperType.Ajax" page-size="80" server-filtering="true">
            <transport>
                <read url="@Url.Action("CategoryVirtualRead", "Products")" />
            </transport>
        </datasource>
        <virtual value-mapper="CategoryMapper" />
        <popup-animation>
            <open duration="500" />
            <close duration="500" />
        </popup-animation>
    </kendo-multiselect>


    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my view model where I bring in my `Products` model and cast my `ProductCategories` and `ProductTags` as a list with their respective model.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProject.Data.ViewModels
{
    public class CreateProductViewModel
    {
        public CreateProductViewModel()
        {
            ProductCategories = new List<ProductCategories>();
            ProductTags = new List<ProductTags>();
        }
        public Products Products { get; set; }
        public List<ProductCategories> ProductCategories { get; set; }
        public List<ProductTags> ProductTags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller for the form where I submit the product data if the model is valid, then I iterate over the results of both categories and tags and post them into their tables.  The problem is, as I said above, they are empty with a count of 0.

**Create**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(CreateProductViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && model !=null)
    {
        try
        {
            var product = new Products
            {
                Id = model.Products.Id,
                Title = model.Products.Title,
                SKU = model.Products.SKU,
                Price = model.Products.Price,
                ShortDescription = model.Products.ShortDescription,
                LongDescription = model.Products.LongDescription,
                StockLevel = model.Products.StockLevel
            };
            _productsService.InsertProduct(product);
            int newId = product.Id;

            //Process Tags
            if (model.ProductTags !=null) {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var tag in model.ProductTags)
                    {
                        var tagItem = new ProductTags
                        {
                            ProductId = product.Id,
                            TagName = tag.TagName
                        };
                        _productTagService.InsertProductTag(tagItem);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                 }
             }
             //Process Categories
             if (model.ProductCategories != null) {
                 try
                 {
                     foreach (var category in model.ProductCategories)
                     {
                         var categoryItem = new ProductCategories
                         {
                             ProductId = product.Id,
                             CategoryName = category.CategoryName
                         };
                         _productCategoryService.InsertProductCategory(categoryItem);
                     };
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                 }
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex) {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         };
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
 }
```

Is my approach to this totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you directly use the form to submit, then it will only pass the `int[] Values` selected by each multipselect, not the corresponding `List<object>`, so the model cannot receive the corresponding two lists of data.

I suggest that you can use the `ajax` method to pass parameters, and get the data selected by each multipselect to `compose the required parameters` ,then pass them to the Create method.

First, add Id to each multipselect ,title input and submit button :

```
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Products" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Products.Title"></label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Products.Title" class="form-control"  id="TitleInput" />
    </div>


        <kendo-multiselect id="ProductTags" name="ProductTags" for="ProductTags" style="width:100%"
            placeholder="Select tags..."
            datatextfield="TagName"
            datavaluefield="Id">
            <datasource type="DataSourceTagHelperType.Ajax" page-size="80" server-filtering="true">
                <transport>
                    <read url="@Url.Action("TagVirtualRead", "Products")" />
                </transport>
            </datasource>
            <virtual value-mapper="TagMapper" />
            <popup-animation>
                <open duration="500" />
                <close duration="500" />
            </popup-animation>
        </kendo-multiselect>

    <kendo-multiselect id="ProductCategories" name="ProductCategories" for="ProductCategories" style="width:100%"
        placeholder="Select categories..."
        datatextfield="CategoryName"
        datavaluefield="Id">
        <datasource type="DataSourceTagHelperType.Ajax" page-size="80" server-filtering="true">
            <transport>
                <read url="@Url.Action("CategoryVirtualRead", "Products")" />
            </transport>
        </datasource>
        <virtual value-mapper="CategoryMapper" />
        <popup-animation>
            <open duration="500" />
            <close duration="500" />
        </popup-animation>
    </kendo-multiselect>


    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then add the following js in this view:

```
<script>
        $("form").submit(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var ProductTags = [];
            var ProductCategories = [];
            $("#ProductCategories option:selected").each(function () {
                var category = {};
                category.Id = $(this).val();
                category.CategoryName = $(this).text();
                ProductCategories.push(category);
            });
            $("#ProductTags option:selected").each(function () {
                var tag = {};
                tag.Id = $(this).val();
                tag.TagName = $(this).text();
                ProductTags.push(tag);
            });
            var createProductViewModel = {
                Products: {
                    Title: $("#TitleInput").val()
                },
                ProductTags: ProductTags,
                ProductCategories: ProductCategories
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Products/Create",
                type: "POST",
                data: createProductViewModel,
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]