# How do I get the values from a Kendo Multiselect when a form is submitted inside of a bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I am using a bootstrap modal in my ASP.NET Core web application, I am also using KendoUI.  On submission of the form, I pass specific data to my controller using Ajax.  One of the problems that I'm having is that, no matter what configuration I use, I can't get the values from my Kendo MutliSelect widget.  Do widgets need to be handled differently in a modal?  All values return `null` whereas other elements such as text inputs work perfectly.

**Modal and Form**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add-custom-view" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add-custom-view" aria-modal="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg modal-notify modal-primary" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">            
            <form id="ModalFormAddCustomView" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="AddCustomView" asp-controller="Position">
                <!-- Jquery finds this element without any problems-->
                <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="ViewName" />

                <!--Jquery can't find this element -->
                <kendo-multiselect name="VesselTypes" style="width:100%"
                      placeholder="Select types..."
                      datatextfield="TypeName"
                      datavaluefield="Id"
                      min-length="3"                                                   
                      height="520">
                      <datasource type="DataSourceTagHelperType.Ajax" page-size="80" server-filtering="true">
                          <transport>
                              <read url="/Vessel/ReadVesselTypes" />
                          </transport>
                      </datasource>                                    
                  </kendo-multiselect>

                  <button type="submit" id="SubmitCustomView" class="btn">
                      Save
                  </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery Function**

```
//On submit
$("#ModalFormAddCustomView").submit(function (e) {
    //Prevent default submission behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get the viewname from the input box
    var viewName = $('#ViewName').val();   

    //Get Vessel Types    
    var vesselTypes = $('#VesselTypes').data("kendoMultiSelect");
    var typesValue = vesselTypes.value();

    //Post data via ajax to the controller.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Position/AddCustomView/',
        data: {
            viewname: viewName,
            types: JSON.stringify(typesValue),
            checkboxes: JSON.stringify(checkboxData)
        },   
        dataType: "json",        
        cache: false,
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success")
        },
        fail: function (data) {
            console.log("failed")
        }
    });
})
```

Can anyone tell me how to locate the kendoui multi select element in the form when it's submitted?

Comment: Is your VesselTypes multiselect getting an ID of "VesselTypes" when it gets rendered in the view? It should I believe, but if it's not that could explain it since you're using the id selector '#'.

Comment: @G_P Yeah it is which is making this even more confusing. I was thinking that perhaps Jquery can't find the element because it's in a modal, I'm not sure about that though.

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371400/how-do-i-capture-kendoui-multiselect-data-in-my-asp-net-core-application/61401755#61401755),and I see you passed data with json type,what is your controller action like,json data can only pass one object.

Comment: Another thing you can check: verify that you only have one element in the rendered view with the ID “VesselTypes”. If it’s not unique, perhaps you’re getting the null/value from the other element?